# How to split text by linefeed and concatenate with variable padding

Tags: xml, xslt

hi here below i have shown my xml existing a value like three line feed but doubt how to fetch a value based on line feed in xslt logic can any help me

```
     <message>
    <block4>
         <tag>
    <name>57D</name>
    <value>BVALESM M0746A
           051028GB ES00069074
           6A051028 GBES00069</value>
         </tag>
    </block4>
</message>
```

here is my xslt which was i was trying but still some issues kindly please suggest me

```
<xsl:when test="tag[name = '57D'] ">
                    <xsl:variable name="l" select="substring-before(tag[name = '57D']/value, '&#13;')"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="r" select="substring-after(substring-before(tag[name = '57D']/value, '&#13;'), '&#13;')"/>


                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(concat($l,'                                   '),1,35),substring(concat($r,'                                   '),1,35))"/>

                </xsl:when>
```

generating output as:

**BVALESM M0746A                     051028GB ES000690746A051028 GBES00069**

it was considering total value after the first clrf so it was not checking logic

required output like

```
BVALESM M0746A                     051028GB ES00069074                6A051028 GBES00069
```

each line max has to be 35 , it was not every time data should come as 35 for each so if not means we need t insert space

Comment: There are three lines in the **value** element. Which line did you want to fetch? Also, will there be a limit on the number of lines that ever appears in the **value** element?

Comment: all the lines i need like after fetch each one i will concat like this concat(line1,line2,line3)

Comment: Read now your comment. if you need concatenation of all lines like that, you need only `normalize-space()` function. Did you miss that? Why precisely you want split by line feed?

Comment: @empo i dont know boss it was decreased. here in above issue y i have particulary asking about linefeed fetch means per each max 35 char vill come, we dunno for every messg each nn every line was max length 35 so if suppose in line1 it wasnt about 35 char then i need to replace remaining characters as space , that logic i vill be handle over , i need only how to fetch the value based on linefeed

Comment: The line you show in the required output has more than 35 characters. What's the point with 35? I don't understand. You can get the same result by `<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(value)"/>`

Comment: Please also make sure to write in clear standard english.

Comment: This is an example of *badly formulated* question. -1.

Comment: @dimitre if you have seen the above xml three lines are existing and hope we need to concentrate for CLRF in between three lines,  output should be concat as line1 line2 line3 , condition we need to check if line1 data was not equal to 35 means we need to padded spaces and it should follows line2 same padded space condition to be apply follows line3 with above padded space condition

Comment: @pravz: Then the answer you accepted doesn't implement the padding requirement. This is what's confusing: you require certain things and you accept an answer that doesn't deliver them.

Comment: @dimitre i accepted answer for tokenize which was working in version 2.0 not for my question sorry if i make a trouble for you,kindly suggest some thing for my requirement

Comment: i have already edited that question ,which was not met my requirements it i have unmarked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the actual question is heavily changed in the requirements since its original formulation. Now I'll provide a new answer.

The following transform behaves as follows:

- Split lines by line-feed (using **split-string** template)
- For each line, check 35 against the string length. If the string is lower than 35, padding is added to fill in the string till 35 (using **padding** template)
- All lines are concatenated

---

[XSLT 1.0]

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="message/block4/tag">
        <xsl:variable name="result">
            <xsl:call-template name="split-string">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="value"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="split-string">
        <xsl:param name="string"/> 
        <xsl:variable name="l" select="substring-before($string, '&#xA;')"/> 
        <xsl:variable name="r" select="substring-after($string, '&#xA;')"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$l">
                <xsl:variable name="spaces">
                    <xsl:call-template name="padding">
                        <xsl:with-param name="times" 
                            select="35 - string-length(normalize-space($l))"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space($l),$spaces)" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($string)" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

        <xsl:if test="$r">
            <xsl:call-template name="split-string">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$r" /> 
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="padding">
        <xsl:param name="times" select="0"/>
        <xsl:param name="spaces" select="''"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when   test="$times>0">
                <xsl:call-template name="padding">
                    <xsl:with-param name="times" select="$times - 1"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="spaces" select="concat($spaces,' ')"/>    
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$spaces"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following input:

```
<message>
    <block4>
        <tag>
            <name>57D</name>
            <value>BVALESM M0746A
                051028GB ES00069074
                6A051028 GBES00069</value>
        </tag>
    </block4>
</message>
```

This output is produced:

```
BVALESM M0746A                     051028GB ES00069074                6A051028 GBES00069
```

Comment: yeah boss i need in xslt 1.0 only, i m googling but i dint get xact solution which what i want

Comment: i edited my requirement can you please see and give me some suggestion please

Comment: Do you need to handle always three lines or they can be more, say 5 or 100 lines?

Comment: @empo let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2326/discussion-between-pravz-and-empo)

Comment: ok, even if you have only 4 lines, I've provided a general solution which can be adapted to as many lines as found. See if my answer is correct. Please provide feedback and accept the answer when satisfied. Cheers

Comment: output was not generated as i am expected, ex : it was generating as line1 with space condition  follows line2 here it was considering the total value as line 3 and line4 as same in line2 concating here output was like :BVALESM M0746A                     051028GB ES000690746A051028 GBES00069

Comment: How are you performing the test? Which processor are you using to transform your data? If you execute the test exactly as I did, you should obtain the wanted result. Please describe better what's happening.

Comment: yeah i did as same as you given code it was splits for line1 it was padded with spaces fine , next we are calling like string after clrf it should consider line2 but was considering total value line3 also not paddind spaces after line2

Comment: The result as resported in the answer is not correct? is the same you requested and is that I'm currently obtaining.

Comment: with based up your sample i have reached required output , thanks empo

Answer (score 0):

there are some options but it heavily depends on your other constraints, mostly related to your xslt processor and its runtime environment:

- can you use xslt 2.0, or need to stick with xslt 1.0 ?
- exslt functions can be helpful: http://exslt.org/str/index.html
- you can also process the data by recursively calling a named template on the data, and use xpath functions substring-before, substring-after - you will probably need also normalize-space to have constant whitespace separator - see http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/ for details